# Error cloning collection using Cosmic Clone

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to clone an existing MongoDB collection that is running on azure cosmos DB to another collection on the same DB using [Cosmic Clone](https://github.com/Microsoft/CosmicClone).

access validation succeeds but the process fails with the following error message:

> Collection Copy log
> Begin Document Migration.
> Source Database: myDB Source Collection: X
> Target Database: myDB Target Collection: Y
> LogError
> Error: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0., Message: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.
> Main process exits with error
> LogError
> Error: One or more errors occurred., Message: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this tool but I took a quick look at the source for it and I'm fairly certain it is not designed to work with MongoDB collections in Cosmos DB.

If you're looking to copy a MongoDB collection you're better off using native Mongo tools like mongodump and mongorestore.

More details here, https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/